# Recursion Fibonacci NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

I am trying to write a fibonacci function recursive in assembly, but I am not sure if I know what I am doing. That's what I have so far but I am getting segmentation fault.
The code gets a number from user and then calculate that number so if n=9 the output is 34.

Code:

```
extern printf, scanf
section .data

format db "%s %d",10,0
format2 db '%ld',0
format3 db "%s ",10,0
str1 db "Chose a number: ",0
str2 db "Result is: ",0

section .bss
n:      resq 1

section .text
global _start

_start:

        call print1 ;choose a number
        mov rdi, format2
        mov rsi, n
        mov rax, 0
        call scanf ;getting number
        
        mov eax, n
        call fib_n
        call print2 ;printing result

exit:   mov rax,60
        xor rdi, rdi
        syscall

fib_n:
    push    rdi
    xor     eax, eax
    cmp     edi, 2
    jb      end            ; fib(1) = 0                                                                                                                                                                     
    mov     eax, 1
    je      end            ; fib(2) = 1                                                                                                                                                                     
    dec     edi
    call    fib_n          ; -> EAX                                                                                                                                                                         
    push    rax            ; (1) Preserve intermediate result!                                                                                                                                              
    dec     edi
    call    fib_n          ; -> EAX                                                                                                                                                                         
    add     eax, [rsp]     ; fib(n) = fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)                                                                                                                                                   
    add     rsp, 8         ; (1)                                                                                                                                                                            
end:
    pop     rdi
    ret

print1:
        mov rdi, format3
        mov rsi,str1                                                                                                   
        mov rax,0
        call printf                                                                                                                                                               
        ret


print2:
        mov rdi,format                                                                                                                                                                    
        mov rsi, str2                                                                                                                                                                
        mov rdx, [n]
        mov rax,0
        call printf                                              \                                                                                                                
        ret
```

Comment: `mov eax, n` should be `mov eax, [n]` .. you want to load the value not the address. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: The initial call to `fib_n` is passing the argument in the wrong register.

Comment: Oh yeah using the correct register also helps :D

Comment: @PeterCordes But isn't `n` used for receiving user input? It's 1 quadword, not a quadword with the value 1.

Comment: @Michael: Apparently I'm not fully awake yet.  Deleted my previous comment.